# LIST to Values: datetime.datetime

Tags: python, numpy, datetime

I have a list in which one element is string and rest of them as numpy.datetime64 .

```
values=['all', numpy.datetime64('2019-08-05T00:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2019-08-05T01:00:00.000000000'), numpy.datetime64('2019-08-05T02:00:00.000000000')]
```

## below line is to convert datetime

```
values=np.array(values[1:len(values)])
values=values.astype("M8[ms]").tolist()
datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 5, 0, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 5, 1, 0), datetime.datetime(2019, 8, 5, 2, 0)
```

But I am not able to convert values[0]to datetime , is there any proxy to convert string values[0]="all" to datetime or instead of writting "all" 2019-09-00 00:00 is also not working , 
How to make values[0]="all" to datetime 
Thank you.

Comment: Please share more of your code, which ´import`s are you using, what exactly is your Error message,  just some more Details

Answer (score 0):

`"all"` has no meaning as a datetime, with what you've provided it's hard to know what you'd even want it converted to.

But since `"all"` is not a datetime in any format I've ever heard of I would say that you need to perform the substitution to whatever you've decided it should be "by hand": look for `"all"` into wherever it could be and if you find it, replace it with whatever datetime should be substituted for it.